# Prometheus not scrapping mysql metrics on the web

Tags: mysql, docker, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-node-exporter

I created a mysql8 docker container like this:

```
$ docker network create db_network

$ docker run -d 
--name mysql80 
--publish 3306 
--network db_network 
--restart unless-stopped 
--env MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword 
--volume mysql80-datadir:/var/lib/mysql 
mysql:8 
--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

Then I configured the docker daemon like this

```
$ vim /etc/docker/daemon.json

{
  "metrics-addr" : " 157.90.21.142:9323",
  "experimental" : true
}

$ systemctl restart docker
```

Then I deployed the mysql exporter like this:

```
$ docker exec -it mysql80 mysql -uroot -p
Enter password:

mysql> CREATE USER 'exporter'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'exporterpassword' WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 3;
mysql> GRANT PROCESS, REPLICATION CLIENT, SELECT ON *.* TO 'exporter'@'%';
```

The mysql80 exporter is in a container like this

```
$ docker run -d 
--name mysql80-exporter 
--publish 9104 
--network db_network 
--restart always 
--env DATA_SOURCE_NAME="exporter:exporterpassword@(mysql80:3306)/" 
prom/mysqld-exporter:latest 
--collect.info_schema.processlist 
--collect.info_schema.innodb_metrics 
--collect.info_schema.tablestats 
--collect.info_schema.tables 
--collect.info_schema.userstats 
--collect.engine_innodb_status
```

If I curl it from my server it scrapes metrics perfectly from mysql80 container.

Then i created the prometheus.yml like

```
$ vim ~/prometheus.yml

global:
  scrape_interval:     5s
  scrape_timeout:      3s
  evaluation_interval: 5s

# Our alerting rule files
rule_files:
  - "alert.rules"

# Scrape endpoints
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['157.90.21.142:9090']

  - job_name: 'mysql'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['mysql80-exporter:9104']

  - job_name: 'docker'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['157.90.21.142:9323']
```

And finally a container was created for prometheus like this.

```
$docker run -d  --name my-prometheus --network db_network  --mount 
type=bind,src="$(pwd)"/prometheus.yml,destination=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml --publish 
published=9090,target=9090,protocol=tcp  prom/prometheus
```

In Prometheus web UI, the docker and prometheus metrics are scrapped perfectly. But, its not scrapping the mysql80-exporter:9104 metrics at all.

Can somebody provide a solution for this?